# How to do PackageSpec() on MacOS for Julia Testing?

Tags: julia

in my Travis build script I have the following:

```
- run: julia --color=yes  -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path=string(pwd(),"Name_Of_Package"))); Pkg.instantiate()'
```

However, this is not a platform-agnostic command as noted [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/julia/#dependency-management). How can I make this command work on MacOS in addition to Linux?

Note: This is the error I am getting:

```
 [2] #clone#2(::Nothing, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GitTools.jl:107
9
 [3] clone at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/GitTools.jl:88 [inlined]
10
 [4] (::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##26#29")){Bool,Pkg.Types.Context,Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}})(::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Types.jl:547
11
 [5] shred!(::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##26#29")){Bool,Pkg.Types.Context,Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}}, ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at ./secretbuffer.jl:184
12
 [6] #handle_repos_develop!#25 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Types.jl:513 [inlined]
13
 [7] #handle_repos_develop! at ./none:0 [inlined]
14
 [8] #add_or_develop#15(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:57
15
 [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
16
 [10] #add_or_develop#14 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:34 [inlined]
17
 [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
18
 [12] #add_or_develop#10 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:32 [inlined]
19
 [13] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
20
 [14] #develop#21 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:75 [inlined]
21
 [15] develop(::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:75
22
 [16] top-level scope at none:0
23
25l25h
24
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Edit:

I updated to use joinpath and still get the following:

```
Run julia --color=yes -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path=joinpath(pwd(),"/nameOfPackage"))); Pkg.instantiate()' 2s
24
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
1
Run julia --color=yes  -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path=joinpath(pwd(),"/nameOfPackage"))); Pkg.instantiate()'
4
   Cloning git-repo `/nameOfPackage `
5
ERROR: failed to clone from /nameOfPackage, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, unsupported URL protocol)
6
Stacktrace:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> path=string(pwd(),"Name_Of_Package")

Use [`joinpath`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.joinpath) to join paths.

Comment: Fixed that, but I am still getting an error. I updated my post above.

Comment: It's worth noting that this seeminlgy works on TravisCI, I am just testing via Github atiosn right now as well.,

Comment: Remove the initial `/`. That results in an absolute path.

Comment: Did that, I think the root of the issue is with PackageSpec()

Comment: ```Run julia --color=yes  -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path=joinpath(pwd(),"NameOfPackage"))); Pkg.instantiate()'
4
   Cloning git-repo `/home/runner/work/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage`
5
ERROR: failed to clone from /home/runner/work/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, unsupported URL protocol)
6
Stacktrace:```

Comment: You are probably creating the path incorrectly. Is the package really at `/home/runner/work/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage/NameOfPackage`?

Comment: By the way, `joinpath(pwd(), "NameOfPackage")` can be simplified to just `"NameOfPackage"`